# Why trim in Postgres 9.3 did not do the work?

Tags: sql, postgresql, trim

We want to trim the leading and trailing space for `resource` column in postgres 9.3 and it seems to be a simple job. Here is the SQL:

```
update tablename set resource=trim(resource);
```

The query is executed in postgres admin tool SQL screen successfully. However the space was not trimmed. Then we executed the SQL by specifying the id:

```
update tablename set resource=trim(resource) where id=723;
```

It returned:

```
Query returned successfully: one row affected, 12 ms execution time.
```

However the result is the same and there is no update. The same SQL is executed in terminal window and nothing happens.

Why `trim` did not work here?

Comment: Are you sure that the characters are regular whitespace? Alternatively you might have a trigger that blocks the update.

Comment: Interesting. When editing the record in app, there are 2 trailing spaces and can delete them. You may be right that it may NOT be the white space which can be trimmed by TRIM. If those are not white space, what could it be? BTW the Rails .strip can delete them(please disregard if not familiar with Rails).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, the character you see is not an actual space.  You can see the ASCII code for it by using:

```
select ascii(left(resource, 1))
from tablename
where id = 723;
```

If you just want to get rid of the first character, you can do:

```
update tablename
    set resource = substring(resource from 2)
    where id = 723;
```

Comment: When running ascii(right(resource,1)), it returns 9 which is a tab. When running ascii(rigth(resource,2)), it returns 32 which is a space.

Comment: The following removed the trailing non-char: update onboard_data_uploadx_user_accesses set resource=regexp_replace(resource, '\W+', '') where id=723;

Comment: @user938363 `trim` only removes spaces (ascii #32), not all white-spaces by default. You can [add a parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) to remove explicit characters, or use [regexp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)-es, like `^\s+` and `\s+$` (`\W+` will remove any non-word character(s) with any position in your column).